# Windows git remote treats quotes inserted in the remote path by the git client literally: how to disable them?

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell, git

I am trying to add a remote with git 2.23.0 on a Windows 10 PC to a git repo on a remote machine running Windows Server 2012 with git 2.34.1.

I set up OpenSSH on the remote using [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH), so SSH logs into Powershell. However Powershell doesn't handle paths wrapped in single quotes like *nix shells do, instead *treating single quotes in paths literally*. This is important because the remote commands `git pull/fetch/ls-remote` wrap the paths they send to the remote in single quotes, as evidenced by trying to `ls-remote`:

```bsh
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git ls-remote user@addr:path_to/repo
17:22:31.451511 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Users/me/Git/mingw64/bin
17:22:31.457170 git.c:440               trace: built-in: git ls-remote user@addr:/path_to/repo/
17:22:31.457170 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: unset GIT_PREFIX; ssh user@addr 'git-upload-pack '\''/path_to/repo/'\'''
fatal: ''/path_to/repo/'' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Note that the first fatal shows `''/path/to/repo''`:

- The outer quotes are from the error message.
- The inner quotes are true quotes due to the command in the third trace: `git-upload-pack '\''/path_to/repo/'\''`.

I am sure that this is the case because if I make a directory literally called `'path_to`, and a repo directory `repo'` within it, it works.

Is there any git client option to disable these single quote wrappings, or a Powershell option to read paths wrapped with single quotes, or maybe even a later version of `git-upload-pack` that strips these quotes out?